# What is in the reduce function arguments in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I understand that the reduce function is supposed to somewhat combine the results of the map function but what exactly is passed to the reduce function?

```
function(keys, values){
  // what's in keys?
  // what's in values?
}
```

I tried to explore this in the Futon temporary view builder but all I got were *reduce_overflow_errors*. So I can't even print the `keys` or `values` arguments to try to understand what they look like.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

My problem is the following. I'm using the temporary view builder of Futon.

I have a set of document representing text files (it's for a script I want to use to make translation of documents easier).

```
text_file:
    id   // the id of the text file is its path on the file system
```

I also have some documents that represent text fragments appearing in the said files, and their position in each file.

```
text_fragment:
    id
    file_id   // correspond to a text_file document 
    position
```

I'd like to get for each text_file, a list of the text fragments that appear in the said file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

> Note on JavaScript API change: Prior to Tue, 20 May 2008 (Subversion revision r658405) the function to emit a row to the map index, was named "map". It has now been changed to "emit".

That's the reason why there is `map`used instead of `emit`it was renamed. Sorry I corrected my code to be valid in the recent version of CouchDB.

**Edit**

I think what you are looking for is a has-many relationship or a join in sql db language. Here is a [blog](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins) article by Christopher Lenz that describes exactly what your options are for this kind of scenario in CouchDB.

In the last part there is a technique described that you can use for the list you want.
You need a map function of the following format

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "text_file") {
    emit([doc._id, 0], doc);
  } else if (doc.type == "text_fragment") {
    emit([doc.file_id, 1], doc);
  }
}
```

Now you can query the view in the following way:

```
my_view?startkey=["text_file_id"]&endkey;=["text_file_id", 2]
```

This gives you a list of the form

- text_file
- text_fragement_1
- text_fragement_2
- ..

**Old Answer**

Directly from the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions)

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
}
```

Reduce functions are passed three arguments in the order key, values and rereduce

Reduce functions must handle two cases:

1. **When rereduce is false:**

   - key will be an array whose elements are arrays of the form [key,id], where key is a key emitted by the map function and id is that of the document from which the key was generated.
   - values will be an array of the values emitted for the respective elements in keys
     i.e. `reduce([ [key1,id1], [key2,id2], [key3,id3] ], [value1,value2,value3], false)`
2. **When rereduce is true:**

   - key will be null
   - values will be an array of values returned by previous calls to the reduce function
     i.e. `reduce(null, [intermediate1,intermediate2,intermediate3], true)`
     Reduce functions should return a single value, suitable for both the value field of the final view and as a member of the values array passed to the reduce function.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how to use that. I edited my first post with details about the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I had already managed to get the result they get in the article, that is a list of (file, text_fragment) couples. But what I'd like is a list of (file, [text_fragment1, text_fragment2...]) where each file appears in only one couple, and the other coordinate of the couple contains all the text fragments corresponding to that file.

Comment: Maybe I missed something since in the article they make a call to "map" instead of "emit". I have no idea where this "map" function comes from and what it does. I think I'm going to give up. I green check you as you completely answered the original question of the topic.